# ggplot2 dotted lines for a subsection of a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame

```
z = data.frame(x = seq(1,10),y = c(1,2,2,3,2,15,2,3,4,2))
```

To get a simple line plot is straight forward. For example this works.

```
p = ggplot() + geom_line(data=z,aes(x,y))
```

I now want to call out the fact that the data point with value 15 is an outlier. To do this, I would like to make the line connecting 5,2 to 6,15 and 7,2 dotted. Can this be done somehow in ggplot2?

Comment: I tried making a variable `linetype=rep(1,10); linetype[5:7]=2` and feeding this in to `aes(x,y,linetype=linetype)` in your `geom_line` but got an error saying that linetype must be constant *within* each line. Hence I think you'll have to draw 3 separate lines: from 1 to 5 (black), 5 to 7 (dotted), and 7 to 10 (black). But let's see, I could be wrong.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee What about `geom_path`?

Comment: The three separate lines was the approach I was going to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make two lines, one dotted for all data, then one solid that excludes the outlier point. This seems to work:

```
ggplot() + geom_line(data=z,aes(x,y), linetype="dotted") + geom_line(data=z, aes(x, replace(y, y==15, NA)))
```